# Office365 SMTP access is very slow

Tags: email, office-365, smtp

I've been given an Office365 account for work, and I'm try to set it up with an SMTP client (to be specific, msmtp, for use with Mutt).  Though the SMTP transfer takes place OK, it takes a long time (> 10 secs) to complete.  I tried using an SMTP server that's [close to me](http://download.priasoft.com/office365/Office365_EndPoints.html) geographically, but that doesn't seem to help. Is there any way I can increase the speed of the transfer?  Do people have more success with other email clients (Thunderbird, Outlook, Apple Mail, etc.)? (Some people suggest [sending the email asynchronously](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6740567/why-does-sending-an-email-take-so-long), but that isn't a real method of increasing the transfer speed.)

EDIT: Using `pod51000.outlook.com` ([source](https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/outlook_com/forum/oemail-oapps/how-do-i-set-up-my-outlookcom-email-account-at/c709befd-be63-475d-b314-b781393d0816)) instead of `smtp.outlook.office365.com` seems to speed up things a bit (~ 6s to send a message instead of usual 10–15s).  I wonder why Microsoft recommends the latter.